# Capistrano deploy to many nodes on the same Cloud Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, capistrano

I have a Cloud Service on Azure comprising of many instances, each of those has the same address eg. `mycloudservice.cloudapp.net` but exposes the ssh service on a random port so that any instance can be accessed from the outside.

The problem is that Capistrano doesn't like this naming, to be more clear:

Using different names everything works fine

```
server 'myservice0.cloudapp.net', user: 'azureuser', roles: %w{web}
server 'myservice1.cloudapp.net', user: 'azureuser', roles: %w{web}
```

But when I use the same name with different ports Capistrano thinks I am just redefining the previous server, so it ends up using only the last one

```
server 'myservice.cloudapp.net', port: 53458, user: 'azureuser', roles: %w{web}
server 'myservice.cloudapp.net', port: 62434, user: 'azureuser', roles: %w{web}
```

Is there any work around to define multiple servers with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano checks for unique server names. You can use ssh aliases in  ~/.ssh/config to workaround the problem.

```
server 'ssh_aliases1', roles: %w{web}
server 'ssh_aliases2', roles: %w{web}
```

And add this to ~/.ssh/config

```
Host ssh_aliases1
  HostName myservice.cloudapp.net
  User azureuser
  port 53458

Host ssh_aliases2
  HostName myservice.cloudapp.net
  User azureuser
  port 62434
```